# How to open R410 chassis

Tags: hardware, dell-poweredge

I just got a brand new R410 server with a single SATA disc, and want to add two 2TB dics to it.

But.. a rather silly problem is preventing me: I cannot open the chassis.

How is the chassis opened? The "cover latch" is set to unlocked, but the top cover will not slide more than a few millimeters.

Answer (score 5):

On the top of the case there's a little "screw" that points to a closed padlock, and can be rotated to point at the open padlock. Give it a little turn, push down, slide the cover back, then remove.

Comment: This answer did the trick for me.